# паззл на canvas js, как сделать, чтобы тянулась только верхняя картинка

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-n-drop

Пишу паззл на canvas js. Есть баг. если перетянуть одну картинку поверх другой, потом они тянутся вместе. Подкиньте, пожалуйста, идею, как это исправить???

```
         mouseDown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            let mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            let mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            dragok = false;

            for (let i = 0; i < rightField.length; i++) {
              let a = rightField[i];
              if (mouseX > a.x && mouseX < a.x + a.s && mouseY > a.y && mouseY < a.y + a.s) {
                dragok = true;
                a.isDragging = true;
                a.isActive = true;
                score++;
              }
            }
            startX = mouseX;
            startY = mouseY;

            for (let j = 0; j < leftField.length; j++) {
              let b = leftField[j];
              if (mouseX > b.x && mouseX < b.x + b.s && mouseY > b.y && mouseY < b.y + b.s) {
                b.isEmpty = true;
              }
            }
          }

          mouseMove(e) {

            let mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            let mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
            let distanceX = mouseX - startX;
            let distanceY = mouseY - startY;

            if (dragok) {

              for (let i = 0; i < rightField.length; i++) {
                let a = rightField[i];
                if (a.isDragging && a.x <= 0) {
                  a.x = 1;
                  dragok = false;
                } else if (a.isDragging && a.x >= containerSize.width - a.s) {
                  a.x = containerSize.width - a.s - 1;
                  dragok = false;
                } else if (a.isDragging && a.y >= containerSize.height - a.s) {
                  a.y = containerSize.height - a.s - 1;
                  dragok = false;
                }
                else if (a.isDragging && a.y <= 0) {
                  a.y = 1;
                  dragok = false;
                }
                else if (a.isDragging) {
                  a.x += distanceX;
                  a.y += distanceY;
                }
              }
              startX = mouseX;
              startY = mouseY;
            }
            playingField.draw();
          }

          mouseUp(e) {

            let mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            let mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            dragok = false;

            for (let j = 0; j < leftField.length; j++) {
              let b = leftField[j];
              for (let i = 0; i < rightField.length; i++) {
                let a = rightField[i];
                a.isActive = false;
                if (mouseX > b.x && mouseX < b.x + b.s && mouseY > b.y && mouseY < b.y + b.s && a.isDragging && b.isEmpty) {
                  a.x = b.x;
                  a.y = b.y;
                  b.isEmpty = false;
                  if (a.value === b.value) {
                    b.isChecked = true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            for (let j = 0; j < rightField.length; j++) {
              rightField[j].isDragging = false;
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Что-то я добавляю ваш код и у меня нет ни картинок, ни перетягиваний. Может уже что-то рабочее предоставите, чтобы было понятно о чем речь. Что-то цельное. Или отдельно проблему, функцию или что там.

Comment: И у вас там скролл не учитывается, что-то не так работает. И зачем вообще позволять класть картинку на занятую клетку? Надо ее закрывать.

Comment: Не нужно менять вопрос, когда вам уже дали ответ. Если возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно (немного запутался, какой вариант вопроса был на момент появления ответа, сейчас вроде правильно)

Comment: Еще раз, если возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, а не редактируйте существующий. Если это тот же вопрос, 1 - не понятно зачем вы отметили ответ как принятый, если он вам не помог, 2 - не понятно зачем вы удаляете код, без кода вам точно никто не поможет.

Comment: Leonid, а скролл нужно учитывать для того, чтобы игра работала ,когда появляется полоса прокрутки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции `mouseDown`, когда определяется над каким элементом находится курсор, нет выхода из цикла. Соответственно, если два (или более) элемента частично перекрывают друг друга и курсор находится сразу над несколькими элементами, то все элементы получат `isDragging = true`.